# Using an Objective-C function to set an integer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an Objective-C function as follows:

```
-(float)getModelTotal: (int)amount forSelector: (NSString*)selectorType;
```

I would like to perform the following steps in a different funciton:

```
float programFee = 1;

float token = [self getModelTotal: object.Alpha forSelector: object.Beta];
programFee += token;
```

`object.Alpha` is an integer and `object.Beta` is an `NSString`.

The function returns a float and I would like to add the result to a different float. When I invoke the function by sending a message to `self`, I get an error and rightfully so because the float is not `self` in this case.

To what receiver should I send this message?

Comment: Are you trying to say that the two methods are defined in different classes? What is the error that you get?

Comment: The two methods are both implemented in the same class definition.

Comment: Ok, and the error is...?

Comment: The error is "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNUmber' to parameter of type int."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, object.alpha is apparently an NSNumber, not an int.

So you should make the call something like this:

[self getModelTotal: [object.alpha intValue] forSelector:object.beta]

Answer (score 1):

That's not a function, it's a method. You should send the message to an instance of whichever class you declared the method on.

If you want a function, declare it C-style, but outside of the `@implementation` block.

---

**Update:** It seems like it's telling you `Object.Alpha` is really an `NSNumber`? Try:

```
float token = [self getModelTotal: [object.Alpha intValue] forSelector: object.Beta];
```

Comment: What if I declare that method inside the class definition, and the method that calls it is also in the class definition.